# React native ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps not working

Tags: react-native, keyboard, scrollview

The button is not clicking after the keyboard is closed.

`keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'` not working.
`keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"` not working.
`keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"` not working.

[image]

react-native : 0.62.2 
react: 16.11.0

Comment: Hi IamTortue, which button you are referring to?. I didn't see any click events inside the scroll view

Comment: Hi Dhevendhiran, There is a button on the product page. [Products page](https://iamtortue.com/a.png)
[Home page](https://iamtortue.com/b.png)